# Formatting currency within a specific precision range

Tags: c#, string-formatting

I am trying to format currency that will always contain 2 decimal digits, but if there are extra digits of accuracy to display up to five. As an example:

```
for value = 5.0 <br />
display: $5.00

for value = 5.023 <br />
display: $5.023

for value = 5.333333333333333 <br />
display: $5.33333
```

I have been playing with the .ToString() formatting, but I can't seem to find the right match of options.

Clarification:
I want to show from 2-5 decimals, truncating zeros after the second digit.

```
for value = 5.000000000000000 <br />
display: $5.00

for value = 5.333333333333333 <br />
display: $5.33333
```

Comment: I saw this in a movie once.

Answer (score 4):

C or c is used for currencies, followed by the number of digits: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
decimal value=1.12345m;
Console.WriteLine("{0:c2}",value);
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("c2"));
```

Will display $1.12

To keep the number of digits between 2 and 5 you have to do some math:

```
    var digits = Math.Min(5, (int)Math.Max((byte)2, BitConverter.GetBytes(decimal.GetBits(value)[3])[2]));
    Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("c" + digits));
```

Comment: Won't this always show only 2 decimals? The goal is to always show at least 2-decimals, but up to 5 if available, truncating zeros after two decimal places.

Comment: True, I added another example to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use also attribute in your model to avoid specifying formatting every time the variable appears.

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="{0:C2}")]
public decimal Value;
```

For non-optional and optional digit use:

```
value.ToString("0.00###");
```

Answer (score 1):

Multiply the value * 100000 then remove any decimal points and divide it / 100000

```
value = value * 100000;
value = Math.Round(value,0);
value = value /100000;
```